# Nose and foot coordinates using key-point R-CNN and DensePose

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, maxima, 3d-reconstruction

Given an image, say, [this](https://bandat-nhontrach.com/images/person-standing-png-3.jpg), I am using the Key-Point R-CNN (from detectron2) to get the coordinates of the nose and either foot. Using [this code](https://github.com/linjunyu/Detectron2-Densepose-IUV2XYZ/blob/master/Detectron2-densepose-IUV2XYZ.ipynb), I get a [3D-reconstruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RReQa.jpg). DensePose changes the person's pose (as shown in the previous link). **Using the 3D model and the key-points, how can I get the 3D coordinates of the nose and feet?** (As of right now, they do not match).
I used the projection of the model to the [Y-Z plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lk2R.jpg)  then tried looking for the right and left most maxima but couldn't find a good enough algorithm.

Thanks!

Comment: You can raise this as an issue in Github from which you are taking the code. This looks a logical doubt rather than any error

Comment: I already did. I got no answer so I tried here.